# Is there a Stack Exchange site for interview questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for both technical and behavioural interview questions? Where I could ask questions about, for example:

- Sample questions and solutions, experiences, or seeking advice for interviews
- A place where I could ask interview questions and what the best way to answer it (not just a correct way or the most efficient).
- What to do in a certain situation such as negotiation, unfair interviews, etc.
- Experiences interviewing at so-and-so company.

Comment: In general, questions like this are typically either too broad (can I haz list of questions please?) or too localized (how do I answer this interview question?).

Comment: As in a list of questions people have been asked, with suggested answers? You might be able to find *individual* questions here and there ([example](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9526)), but they have to be carefully worded to get around the "primarily opinion-based" or "too broad" rules.

Comment: Related else-meta (P.SE): [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-programmers-se-questions)

Comment: Related else-meta (TWP.SE): [What determines if a question about interview questions is on-topic?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/what-determines-if-a-question-about-interview-questions-is-on-topic)

Answer (score 20):

To directly answer your question, no, there isn't really a single site where you can ask *any* question you would find in *any* interview. It depends on the question - there are a lot of different things that can be covered in an interview, and many of them will be inherently specific to your particular vocation.

As mentioned in the question comments, [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) might be the best candidate for general questions ("What are your weaknesses", "Where do you see yourself in five years"), although you'll still need to make sure that you have [a real, answerable question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

For software developers, and for questions that are not directly about code but that are still software-related, the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) does allow some interview questions, although again you'll want to make sure it [meets their requirements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they seem to [get a lot of poor examples](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-programmers-se-questions). Stack Overflow would likely be the best candidate for code-based questions, or maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you just want to assess what you came up with.

Comment: Interview questions don't fare well on Stack Overflow.  We expect questions to be practical and answerable, not the "how many jellybeans can fit into a bus" variety.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: It says for code-based questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I edited the answer to prevent quick scan misinterpretation.

Comment: since the time this was posted, Programmers became stricter in that regard, see **[Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)** Consider [edit]ing to account for that

Comment: I've already got a link to that very page - under 'get a lot of poor examples'

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=interview) where they have an interview tag and a few good interview posts.

Make sure your post fits the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)'s guidelines before posting.