# Where can I ask interview related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Interview, asking for offer etc. I wonder if Stack Exchange has a sote for this kind of question?

Sample question:

> Do company usually do not reveal their benefit package until you sign the accepting offer letter?

Comment: related: [Is there a Stack Exchange site for interview questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215968/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-interview-questions)